# Вживання слова "везе"

Tags: вживання-слів

Коли людина має несподіваний успіх у якійсь справі, кажуть, що їй *щастить*, *таланить*. Також безліч таких прикладів в художній літературі. Але останнім часом досить поширеним в українській мові стало слово *везе*. Щодо розмовної мови, мабуть, доцільно його використовувати. А як щодо офіційно-ділового стилю? Чи буде доцільно вживати *"везе"* в офіційно-діловому стилі?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Оскільки лексема "везе" у початковій формі буде "везти", то ж у сучасному [Словнику української мови](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=7219&page=266) читаємо статтю, де подається така інформація:

> **ВЕЗТИ́**, зу́, зе́ш; мин. ч. віз, везла́, ло́; недок. 2. безос., кому і без дод., ***розм.*** Щастити, таланити.
>
> – Не везе, брат, мені, ні в чому на світі не везе!(Панас Мирний);
>
> Сьогодні знов страшенний дощ, мокро і холодно. Не везе з погодою (М. Коцюбинський);
>
> – Як добре, що я вас зустрів.., мені просто везе
> (Іван Ле).

Якщо ж у статті подається мітка *"розм"* тобто розмовне, робимо висновок, що таке слово можна використовувати у розмовному стилі, але в офіційно-діловому НЕ варто.